# excel vba copy cells to another sheet if cell value is greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy cell values if a cell value in another column is greater than 0.

In Sheet1:

G3 : G25 = Name

L3 : L25 = ActiveX Check box (if checked then price shows, else price = empty)

M3 : M25 = Price (corresponding to name)

In Sheet2:

A82 : A104 = empty cells

I want to copy Names on G to empty cells (Sheet2), if the price is shown (which means cells on L are checked).

This is what I've tried but I'm getting an error.

```
Sub option_list()
    Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    j = 82

    For i = 3 To 25
        If Source.Cells(i, 13).Value = 0 Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Source.Cells(i, 10).Copy
            Target.Cells("A" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your problem, but what you should never ever do is modify the running variable of a `For`-loop inside the loop (in your case `i`)

Comment: Invert the `If` (or `> 0`) and remove the `i = i + 1`  and `Else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work in your intended way.

- The for loop will always take the next value in the iteration, therefore we can remove `i = i + 1`.
- Since we want to copy everytime we have a value that is not 0, we can express this as `<> 0`
- I think you get an error here, since you mixed it how we write for `range()`. For `cells()` it's a bit different. This part will cause error: `Target.Cells("A" & j)`. The `cells` is written like: `Cells(row, column)` -> `Cells(j, "A")`.

**Full revised code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub option_list()
Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

j = 82

For i = 3 To 25
    If Source.Cells(i, 13).Value <> 0 Then
        Source.Cells(i, 10).Copy
        Target.Cells(j, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use Copy & Paste (or PasteSpecial) when you only want to copy values. Use `Target.Cells(j, "A") = Source.Cells(i, 10)`

Comment: Thanks a lot and also for the comment !